# How to get server base path to find and read a json

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, mocking, websphere-liberty

I have this rest and I'm trying to mock some responses
I'm working on a **WebSphere** server with **Spring Boot**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, "application/hal+json"})
public Resources<String> getAssemblyLines() throws IOException {
    String fullMockPath = servletContext.getContextPath() + "\\assets\\services-mocks\\assembly-lines\\get-assembly-lines.ok.json";
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    result.add(fullMockPath);

    try {
        byte[] rawJson = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fullMockPath));
        Map<String, String> mappedJson = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String jsonMock = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(mappedJson);
        result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.add(jsonMock);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result.add("Not found");
        result.add(e.getMessage());
    }

    return new Resources<String>(result,
            linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).getAssemblyLines()).withSelfRel());
}
```

I get

> FileNotFoundException

Tired Tushinov's solution

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

But that returns the PATH of my server, not of my document root (and yes, they're in different folders)

How can understand my base path?

Answer (score 1):

To your question `How can understand my base path?`. You can use:

> System.getProperty("user.dir")

`System.getProperty("user.dir")`will return the path to your project.

Example output:

> C:\folder_with_java_projects\CURRENT_PROJECT

So if the file is inside your project folder you can just do the following:

`System.getProperty("user.dir") + "somePackage\someJson.json";`

Comment: Interesting...Is there a way to get the path to the current file instead?

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you give me some more information ?

Comment: What I could really use is to get the path of the current package, or the current script (class), like I do in PHP and then I could use relative path!

Comment: I tought about it and came up with an idea. You can use the "System.getProperty("user.dir")" to get your project folder as i said and after that you can use 
String currentPackage= "this.getClass().getPackage().getName().replace(".", File.separator);" 

The operation above will return the package of the class from which it was called and then you can just add things up.
System.getProperty("user.dir") + currentPackage + "yourfile.json"

Comment: Cool. I'll try it on monday. I'll select your answer anyway. I'll take your word for it ahahahh :)

Comment: Cheers mate ! Hope ive been of help.